# How to convert the array of datetime to get the time only (HH:mm)

Tags: powershell

Need your help on how to convert the datetime array results to get the time only `HH:mm`. Below is the sample result set:

```
$tableRt

RecordedTime         
------------         
2/18/2018 1:18:04 PM

2/18/2018 1:23:02 PM 

2/18/2018 1:28:04 PM 

2/18/2018 1:33:02 PM 

2/18/2018 1:38:05 PM 

2/18/2018 1:43:02 PM
```

Answer (score 3):

Just cast your pipeline object ot `[datetime]` and format it. Example:

```
$tableRt = @(
'2/18/2018 1:18:04 PM'
'2/18/2018 1:23:02 PM'
'2/18/2018 1:28:04 PM'
'2/18/2018 1:33:02 PM'
'2/18/2018 1:38:05 PM'
'2/18/2018 1:43:02 PM'
)


$tableRt | ForEach-Object {
    ([datetime]$_).ToString("HH:mm")
 }
```

**Output:**

```
13:18
13:23
13:28
13:33
13:38
13:43
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I encountered error when I tried to cast the datatable results.

Here's the sample code that I used:

$TableRT = $Table | select-object "RecordedTime"


$RecordedTime = @( Foreach ($Row in $TableRT) { $Row[0]}) 

$RecordedTime | ForEach-Object { ([datetime]$_).ToString("HH:mm")}

Comment: here's the error message:
Error Message:
Cannot convert value "@{RecordedTime=2/19/2018 2:30:01 PM}" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "Cannot convert the "@{RecordedTime=2/19/2018 2:30:01 PM}" value of type "Selected.System.Data.DataRow" to type "System.DateTime"."
At line:3 char:5
+     ([datetime]$_).ToString("HH:mm")

Comment: Please start a new question, reading code in comment is no fun and I need something that is reproducable.

Comment: @PSNewbie you probably need to use `$tableRt.RecordedTime | foreach...`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice guys, I was able to resolved the code and get desired output.

```
$FinalTable = @()
$FinalTableVar = New-Object System.Object
foreach ($data in $Table)
{
#$data
$RecordedTime = Get-Date -Date $data.RecordedTime -Format HH:mm
$FinalTableVar = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
RecordedTime = $RecordedTime
Connections = $data.Connections

}
$FinalTable += $FinalTableVar

}

$RT = $FinalTable | select-object "RecordedTime"
```

Sample Ouput:

```
> $RT

RecordedTime
------------
15:28       
15:33 
15:38
```